# How to set display name in Sitecore Gutter always on English

Tags: multilingual

how can I setup all items display name in English in Sitecore Gutter.

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore does not provide this functionality OOTB but we can create a custom Sitecore Gutter, also known as a quick action bar.

You need to follow the below steps -

- Create a class that inherits the GutterRenderer.
- Override the GutterIconDescriptor method in the GutterRenderer class, to set the appropriate icons to the gutter.

  ```
  public class GutterItemDisplayName : GutterRenderer
   {
       //Example code
       protected override GutterIconDescriptor GetIconDescriptor(Item item)
       {
           String displayName = GetDisplayName(item);
           GutterIconDescriptor descriptor = new GutterIconDescriptor();

               descriptor.Icon = "Applications/32x32/document_ok.png";//Icon to show in Gutter
               descriptor.Tooltip = "Items display name is "+ displayName; //Tooltip will show item display name
               descriptor.Click = //Any action you want to add for the item;
               return descriptor;

       }
   }
  ```
- Create Custom Gutter in core database under `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Gutters` using this template-  `/sitecore/templates/Sitecore Client/Content editor/Gutter Renderer`
- Populate the **Header** and **Type** fields of the Gutter, **Header** field should contain the name you want to give to the Gutter, **Type** field should contain the fully qualified class name, the dll which contains the class.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will want to have all display items to be automatically used English version.

Comment: I mean this section on other language version must be always on English:  
Display name - Is shown in the content editor

Comment: @eratosten123 In the `GetDisplayName` function, you need to find the Display name for the English language. correct me if I am understand your requirement incorrect here

Comment: Ok, I will try like that

Comment: I mean I need that for site tree

Comment: is it something you want? - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14787/is-there-an-option-to-only-show-item-names-not-display-names-in-the-content-tr

Comment: Yes, it looks like it, I will check it, thank you!